# Configuring AMPPS to allow CGI scripts to run

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

Im using AMPPS, I can't access my perl file, but I can every other file in the folder.
I'm getting a 403 forbidden.

Here's the code:

```
[Fri Jan 24 01:18:10.069985 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 38441] [client ::1:51823] Options  
ExecCGI is off in this directory: /Applications/AMPPS/www/test/test1.pl, referer: 
http://localhost/test/test1.html
```

I'm calling the perl file via an AJAX POST call

Things I have tried:

1. Adding `+ExecCGI` to every < Directory > structure I can find
2. Adding `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl to the aforementioned structures`
3. Setting 777 permissions recursively the containing folder, along with the cgi-bin directory set by `ScriptAlias` in the httpd.conf.

Is there anyone that can give me some insight as to either:

- What I'm doing wrong
- How to configure the httpd.conf standard config file to run CGI scripts from the /www folder using AMPPS

  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing looks fine. Just make sure that you include your httpd.conf in the apache2.conf file and recheck the directory path where you are giving your +ExecCGI and AddHandler options.

I am not sure about AMPPS, but thinking apache server settings will be same.
Looking at the log , looks like your directory path should be : /Applications/AMPPS/www/ .

And make sure you restart the server after each change you make.